# Tikz - image and text inside circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I want to have the following layout:
[image]

What I have is the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (2,2) circle (2.5cm);
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (myfirstpic) at (2,2.6) {\includegraphics[width=.09\textwidth]{info.png}};
        \node at (2,1) {{\LARGE Andreas}};
    \end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

This is working, but sometimes I don't know what contents are placed inside the circle. 
I'd like to know if there is a simpler or cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt,above] (n1) {\includegraphics[width=.09\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\node [font=\LARGE,below] (n2) {Andreas};
\node [draw, circle, minimum size=5cm, fit= (n1) (n2)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Size of circle is determined by `minimum size which is equal to diameter of circle.

[image]

**Addendum:**
A simpler solution without use of `fit` libraries:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm]
\node[inner sep=0pt,above] (n1) {\includegraphics[width=.09\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\node [font=\LARGE, below] (n2) {Andreas};
\draw(0,0) circle[radius=2.5cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as above, width of circle is now  determined with radius of circle

Comment: This is working fine. Can I set the circle to a fixed width as well?

Comment: @AndiLeni, circle has width defined with `minimum size=5cm`. Now i add even simpler solution.